# Adding a camera to a turtlebot (not in simulation)

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, realsense, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1- I have a turtlebot and I wanna add a realsense camera on the top of it but I am wondering what should I do to calibrate the base of the camera and the robot. What should I add and where ?

2- If i wanna add more realssense camera's should I also line the cameras together or just with the robot ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Jad

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306615/adding-a-camera-to-a-turtlebot-(not-in-simulation)/) by [Jad](https://answers.ros.org/users/35872/jad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2018-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you need only a valid TF for you  Realsense camera to one existig frame and you are Finished. TF mange evertring else.

you can put you camera every you want. But as the realsens also use Structerd light you may do not look  them at the same spot.

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2019-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0